# What is the difference between Windows 8 Store App developed using HTML/Javascript and XAML/C#

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

What are the differences between these two programming choices

I know that the following features are supported by only HTML/Javascript
1. Flyout control
2. Header Menu
3. Rating Control

Do they have any other difference in terms of controls, integrations, connections, deployment?

Comment: This question can have lots of answers and is not a good fit for SO.

Answer (score 3):

**html/javascript**

html5 and js are open web standards. That's why they work (and act) in nearly every browser the same way. That is the reason why you can develop html5 applications for Mac OS and port it without many extra coding to Windows. 
Microsoft however wants to have as many Apps inside the market as possible, that's why they made confession to the web developer and implemented a native looking support to html and Javascript. But there are a lot of Javascript functions, that are only supported by IE10 (in fact, nearly every function you can find in the WinJS-File). If you want to port Win 8 Application to any other Operation System, you have to review your code. 
A good example for this is the click-eventhandler in WinJS, which has a event.pointerId to identify multitouch. This is a good easy way but not standard.

**XAML/C# or VB**

XAML is .NET and so it is fixed to this Framework. You cannot easily port a XAML Application to a mac os. Therefor XAML and C# is very good implemented into Visual Studio (Intellisense,Blend and Design-Views) and has some nice features like [LINQ](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19154/Understanding-LINQ-C) and [DataBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758320.aspx). Also the [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) pattern allows to split up designers and programmers. In my opinion the documentation on msdn is better for XAML and C# than for Html5 and JS. For games there is also a DirectX implementation which is a better choice because of higher performance.

**What to choose?**

The decision which way to program is really hard. The following Questions should help:
Which programming language are you more familiar with?

- IF OOP -> C# and XAML
- IF web and prototype based languages -> HTML and JS

Which type of application will you code?

- If it's fixed to Win 8 -> XAML and C#
- If it should run on more than one platform -> HTML and JS

Do you like Visual Studio?

- If yes -> use XAML and C#
- If no -> use HTML and JS, you can than
  first develop the app with your common IDE and later import it into
  visual studio to create the application.